# Can gdal be used to generate a single patch of the HEALPix projection?

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system

Given a geo-referenced map of the world, I am able to produce a version with a HEALPix projection using gdalwarp like this:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs '+proj=healpix +a=1 +ellps=WGS84 +wktext' -te -3.14159265 -1.57079632 3.14159265 1.57079632 -wo sample_steps=1000 -r cubic world.tiff healpix.tiff
```

A HEALPix projected world map can be subdivided in twelve square patches, like this:

[image]

My goal is not to generate the entire map, but one specific patch only. So if I want to create patch 3, the result should look like this:

[image]

The closest I got to this goal is to use the -te parameter to crop the target region to the bounding box of the patch. Since the origin of the HEALPix coordinates is in the center of patch 6, this would be `-te 0 0 π/2 π/2` for patch 3. However, in order to get to the desired image, two further steps are required which can be done with image processing tools like imagemagick: I have to rotate the result by 45° and crop some corners.

While this is not impossible (in fact, the "desired result image" above has been created this way), it is ineffective and prone to precision issues because the input image is resampled multiple times during the process.

So here comes the question:

**Is there some way to make gdalwarp produce the image above directly, without the need for any further steps?**

The best would be something like the -te parameter but with the possibility to specify four corners and not four extends...